# Can't download Aptana studio 3 eclipse plugin - no repository available

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aptana, aptana3

For the past few days, I've been receiving the same error when trying to install the Aptana 3 plugin for Eclipse:

"No repository found at http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install."

Is this issue known and is wide spread?  Is there an alternative method for downloading and installing this plugin?

I'm trying to install it on Eclipse JavaEE Indigo and I've done it successfully already on another machine but that was a few months.

Any help will be great appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems aptana has set up a CDN (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) to deliver their update site and it seems to be broken... I don't see any solution appart having the CDN configuration fixed.

You should ask in the aptana forum in order to get attention of the aptana ops.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the help; it's good to know I'm not losing my mind!  Regarding forums, it appears that all links for a Aptana Studio3 redirect to stackoverflow ... am I missing it?

Comment: I added the aptana tag, since it seems the one used for their support on stackoverflow. Let's see what happen.